# Reducing memory usage of very large HashMap

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, hashmap

I have a very large hash map (2+ million entries) that is created by reading in the contents of a CSV file.  Some information:

1. The HashMap maps a String key (which is less than 20 chars) to a String value (which is approximately 50 characters).
2. This HashMap is initialized with an initial capacity of 3 million so that the load factor is around .66.
3. The HashMap is only utilized by a single operation, and once that operation is completed, I "clear()" it.  (Although it doesn't appear that this clear actually clears up memory, is a separate call to System.gc() necessary?).

One idea I had was to change the HashMap to HashMap and use the hashCode of the String as the key, this will end up saving a bit of memory but risks issues with collisions if two strings have identical hash codes ... how likely is this for strings that are less than 20 characters long?

Does anyone else have any ideas on what to do here?  The CSV file itself is only 100 MB, but java ends up using over 600MB in memory for this HashMap.

Thanks!

Comment: How about using an Embedded Database such as HSQLDB or SQLite. http://hsqldb.org/ http://www.sqlite.org/

Comment: Using a hashcode where you want a unique value will always lead to trouble.  "Likely" isn't the problem: there's simply not enough bits in a hashcode to uniquely specify a 20 character string.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have the framework to try this already.  Instead of adding the string, add the `string.hashCode()` and see if you get collisions.

In terms of freeing up memory, the JVM generally doesn't get smaller, but it will garbage collect if it needs to.

Also, it sounds like you might have an algorithm that doesn't need the hash table at all.  Could you describe what you're trying to do in a little more detail?

Comment: Sure, I have a CSV that maps a String code to a String description.  Then I have a separate CSV file where one of those columns is the code.  When I'm processing that 2nd CSV file I need to using the description and not the code.  This is where the generated HashMap comes into play.  Once that operation is done, the mapping from code->description is no longer needed.

Comment: One idea: if your second file doesn't use all the codes in the first, then parse that file first and load your hash table with only the codes you know you'll need.  It's an extra run through the file, but possibly worth it if you only have to load a fraction of the first.

Comment: Another idea, if you can process your second file in a different order, then sort both the first and second file by ID.  Then you can iterate along the first file until you see the ID you haven't processed yet in the second; stop process all those IDs in the second file, the proceed to the next ID on the first.  This way you won't have to store *anything* in memory, but with the cost of first sorting the files in some reasonable order.

Answer (score 1):

Parse the CSV, and build a Map whose keys are your existing keys, but values are Integer pointers to locations in the files for that key.

When you want the value for a key, find the index in the map, then use a RandomAccessFile to read that line from the file. Keep the RandomAccessFile open during processing, then close it when done.

Answer (score 1):

what you are trying to do is exactly a JOIN operation. Try considering an in-memory DB like H2 and you can achieve this by loading both CSV files to temp tables and then do a JOIN over them.
And as per my experience h2 runs great with load operation and this code will certainly  be faster and less memory intensive than ur manual HashMap based joining method.

Answer (score 0):

If performance isn't the primary concern, store the entries in a database instead. Then memory isn't a concern, and you have good, if not great, search speed thanks to the database.

Comment: Assuming a DB is not feasible, would using an in-memory DB work?  I would assume it might have some optimizations over using the standard java HashMap.